# How can I pull the value of the key "headerText" from JSON into the result div

Tags: jquery, json

Given my JSON file, I want to display the value of the headerText in the results div, when the user selects a given option from the dropdown menu, supplied by the JSON:

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
<select id="dropdown">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="fetch">Fetch JSON</a>
```

JSON

```
var json = {
"dropdown": [
{
    "optionText": "Budget Starter",
    "headerText": "Work 1-on-1 with your expert to build new spending habits (and break some old ones). Get on a real, sustainable budget that fits your lifestyle.",
    "color": "#59c5c7"
},
{
    "optionText": "5 Year Planner",
    "headerText": "Declare what you want - freedom from debt, security for your family, or an amazing trip. Your expert will build you a custom plan to help you get there.",
    "color": "#009cd0"
},
{
   "optionText": "Portfolio Builder",
    "headerText": "Start training for the world's hardest game: investing. Your expert will help you grow into a disciplined and balanced portfolio manager.",
    "color": "#39ad74"
}
]
};
```

jQuery

```
$('#fetch').click(function() {
$.post('/echo/json/', {json: JSON.stringify(json)}, function(data) {
    $.each(data.dropdown, function(i, v) {
        $('#dropdown').append('<option value="' + v.color + '">' + v.optionText + '</option>');
    });
});
});
//change color of header container based on dropdown selection
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
$("#result").css("background-color", $(this).val());
}).change();
```

CSS

```
#result{height: 50px;}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to append a jquery element? instead of: `$('#dropdown').append('<option value="' + v.color + '">' + v.optionText + '</option>');` try `$('#dropdown').append($('<option value="' + v.color + '">' + v.optionText + '</option>'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you might want to implement this using the [data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/). It allows you to store arbitrary objects alongside DOM elements.

Modified jQuery (see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FqEA9/) here)

```
$('#fetch').click(function() {
$.post('/echo/json/', {json: JSON.stringify(json)}, function(data) {
    var dropdown = $('#dropdown');
    $.each(data.dropdown, function(i, v) {
        var option = $('<option value="' + v.color + '">' + v.optionText + '</option>');
        option.data('header', v.headerText).appendTo(dropdown);
    });
});
});
//change color of header container based on dropdown selection
$("#dropdown").change(function() {
$("#result").css("background-color", $(this).val()).text($(this).find('option:selected').data('header'));
}).change();
```

Comment: This isn't allowing me to pull the headerText from JSON into the result div based on the option selected from the dropdown.

Comment: using `.text($(this).data('header'))` doesn't give me the headerText

Comment: It's `$(this).data('header')` that should return the header text while `.text()` sets the text-node value of the div. Did you include the reimplementation of the ajax callback where the header text is stored? Does the call to `data('header')` not return the value stored?

Comment: My mistake: Within the `change()` callback, `this` is a reference to the select, not the option. Therefore you should use `$(this).find('option:selected').data('header')` to get the header text of the selected option. I'll edit my post.